# How to match air photo to existing vector layers on Mac OS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing, mac

I'm trying to add an air photo to a project and match it to existing data. CanVec data is mostly based on the old CIA dataset of the 60's and is hopelessly out of date, but the roads are up to date - the roads can easily be seen on the air photo. So, I need to use the roads to line the photo up. This will be an iterative process, of course.

I read of a Georeferencer plugin for QGIS, but can't persuade QGIS to find it (it doesn't seem to have the "3rd party" option shown by online tutorials). Will it do what I need it to? If so, how can I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac, Georeferencer is still missing, see

> http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2011-November/014269.html
>
> http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3743
>
> http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4289.
>
> http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Georeferencer-bug-3743-fix-td4683688.html

You could install Oracle Virtual Box, and set up an Ubuntu operating system with QGIS within that.

Comment: I'll pass on that... Is there anything independent that would let me georeference to a format that QGIS accepts? Besides XY position, Xscale and Yscale, it would have to be able to set reference direction.

Comment: I have wine installed...

Comment: QGIS should work on wine. Georeferencer runs fine in the Windows build.

Comment: I found the GeoTIFF spec, converted the photo to TIFF and added a .tfw file. After a dozen or so iterations, it's aligned as accurately as the CanVec data is. Wouldn't want to do it very often...

Answer (score 1):

Georeferencer is available by default. In QGIS 1.8 go Raster-> Georeferencer -> Georeferencer.

Comment: Sorry, SS_R, there is no Georeferencer listed under raster here: 1.8.0 Lisboa on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Georeferencer listed in 1.8 version, then download the "Master Branch just Prior to New Vector API Merge (most compatible with Python plugins)" in [Nightly Mac Build of QGIS from 'master' Branch](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/) of Larry Shaffer.

Georeferencer is available by default in Raster-> Georeferencer

Comment: Tried it, but got a heap of Python error messages and nothing is added under raster. I guess it needs new versions of Python & maybe other stuff than I got with the 1.8.0 instal.